# How do I make a character green using a 4th level or higher spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen

I'm running Hoard of the Dragon Queen and the party has opted to travel as merchants instead of joining the party as guards. Since I was stressing that they were noticing that

> the one wagon they knew belonged to the cultists wasn't accepting riders,

… I had Green Imsa try to obtain passage with them. I was not expecting them to take her on and I definitely wasn't expecting the wizard to hit her with *Dispel Magic*.

Since I was short on planning time prior to the session I hadn't fleshed out Green Imsa a lot. I figured I could just have her evade questions about what happened to her as is supplied in the adventure and then figure out what happened later.

Are there any magical effects ( if its a spell, it must be 4th level or higher) that can turn characters green?

Comment: This sounds like it’s looking for brainstorming rather than a correct answer. Unfortunately this site doesn’t accommodate brainstorming, so we recommend instead using a discussion site for getting ideas from people. We have put together [a list of RPG discussion sites](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) to help people find one. If this *isn't* a request for ideas, you can [edit] your post to demonstrate that.

Comment: Did you have dispel magic fail? Must it be a spell or are other options available? Also, if I recall correctly, Green Imsa was already in the caravan with the cultists. What made her switch wagons?

Comment: In addition to what SSD said, you can bring your brainstorm to the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) and ask members for ideas.

Comment: I've made an edit in an attempt to make the question more in line with site guidelines. Feel free to roll-back the edit if you don't agree with it, or edit it further to be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks @PremierBromanov. I think that works better. Thanks also for the spoiler catch.

Comment: @DavidCoffron, it doesn't have to be a spell per se but the effect did register as arcane in nature to the party. My interpretation of the NPC list from Episode 4 was that they could be used in any capacity to populate the caravan, as cultist or other members of the caravan.

Comment: @crunchykids Your way of including Green Imsa into the party's wagon was fine (in fact, it was creative and probably made the party feel more involved in the story). I was just curious of your approach.

Comment: "or hoigher" doesn't exclude any spells  -any spells can be cast from a higher slot perhaps for metamagic effects.

Comment: @Jasen I think the reason for the "4th level or higher" requirement is to make *Dispel Magic* cast on the magically-green creature more difficult (i.e. not an auto-success)

Comment: wouldn't level of slot used to cast the spell  caster suffice to prevent the dispel or detect?

Answer (score 7):

### Who says it’s a spell?

She’s green - the book doesn’t suggest that this is caused by a spell. In fact, it doesn’t suggest much of anything at all. She’s going to Waterdeep to seek a cure - if *Dispel Magic* was the cure she could get that almost anywhere.

### There are things in the world PCs can’t do or undo

The Forgotten Realms is a high fantasy setting with artefacts of long forgotten races, inherently wonderful flora and fauna and god’s and demons who are objectively real, present and with powers far beyond mortal understanding let alone ability.

Almost anything could have turned her green.

### Instantaneous spells can’t be dispelled

*Dispel Magic* only stops ongoing magical effects - even if the thing that turns her green was a spell, it is not *keeping* her green now and therefore can’t be dispelled.

### Spells that could do it

Wish can do anything.

True Polymorph could also work if the DM is ok with “another kind of creature” being “you, but green”.